# loop through variable stopped working

Tags: shell-script, zsh, variable

I had a working shell script to assign a different layout to an external USB keyboard when it is plugged in, and it no longer works. I don't know it is because I switch from sh to zsh.

```
usbkbd_id="$(xinput -list | grep "USB Keyboard" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | grep "keyboard" | cut -c 1-2)"
for ID in $usbkbd_id; do
    setxkbmap -device ${ID} -layout "es"
done
```

I've noticed that when I checked it with command `echo "device: ${ID} layout: ${usbkbd_layout}" >> test.txt` in deed it's not looping through each ID, but simply adding "device: "at the beginning of the whole first variable output...

I've gone through similar questions and answers, trying different alternatives I've seen, like `${usbkbd_id[@]}`, with my beginner level scripting skills, but I couldn't solve this problem.

Actually, maybe the real problem at the root is that I always get 3 IDs for my external USB keyboard, and actually assigning the keyboard layout to only one of them is effective, and I can't determine which. So sometimes this command works, sometimes it doesn't (when the correct ID is not the last one I guess).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks! I've quoted both "$usbkbd_id" and "${ID}" now. I still get the same output if I send the output to a txt file though. Are you sure this will work? Switching was prompted just for better looks (like oh-my-zsh), I have to confess. ;-)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh, yes, "Zsh does not split unquoted $usbkbd_id" does not necessarily mean "Zsh does split quoted $usbkbd_id", my mistake. ;-) I'll see if I can find a solution within zsh. Or just use bash for this script? Thanks...

Comment: BTW if you have the full name of the device you might be able to use `xinput list --id-only 'actual name of USB Keyboard device'`

Comment: @rowboat Thanks a lot! Actually it seems I was also too lazy to try and single out the Device ID I need from several IDs I get from `xinput -list | grep "USB Keyboard"`. Now `xinput list --id-only 'SEM USB Keyboard' will result in a cleaner command (excluding 2 IDs for 'SEM USB Keyboard Consumer Control'  and 1 ID for 'SEM USB Keyboard System Control' which apparently I don't need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var=value` is a scalar assignment. It assigns **one** and only one value to `$var`. You might have been confused by the behaviour of `sh` where it's also a scalar assignment but since `sh` does not have list/array variables, the expansion of variables, when not quoted undergoes a special split+glob operation (cause of [many bugs and security issues in general](/q/171346) and fixed in most more modern shells, including `rc`, `es`, `fish` or `zsh`).

Here, since you want to store several values, you want to use an array/list variable, not a scalar variable.

In `zsh`, array variable assignment is done with the:

```
var=( values )
```

syntax.

So:

```
usbkbd_ids=(
  $(xinput list | grep -Po 'USB Keyboard.*id=\K\d+(?=.*keyboard)')
)
for id in $usbkbd_ids; do
    setxkbmap -device $id -layout es
done
```

Though here, you might as well do:

```
xinput list |
  grep -Po 'USB Keyboard.*id=\K\d+(?=.*keyboard)' |
  xargs -I ID setxkbmap -device ID -layout es
```

Note that you rarely need to pipe `awk`, `grep` and `cut` together as `awk` is a superset of both other commands. However, `awk` is not very good at pattern-based extractions (unless you can use GNU `awk` extensions). Above that `-P` is a non-standard `grep` extension. As a standard alternative, you could use `sed` as:

```
  xinput list |
    sed -n 's/^.*USB Keyboard.*id=\([0-9]*\).*keyboard.*/\1/p'
```

With standard `awk`, that could be:

```
xinput list |
  awk '/USB Keyboard.*id=.*keyboard/ && match($0, /id=[0-9]+/) {
         print substr($0, RSTART + 3, RLENGTH - 3)
       }'
```

You could also use `zsh`'s own pattern extraction features like:

```
usbkbd_ids=()
for line (${(f)"$(xinput list)"})
  [[ $line =~ 'USB Keyboard.*id=([0-9]+).*keyboard' ]] &&
    usbkbd_ids+=$match[1]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Worked like magic! And learned a little more about shell scripting. ;-)